# ANSI art from image with specific character sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, ansi-escape

I am working on creating a small utility that will take an image and a sequence of characters and then convert the image into ANSI using the sequence or characters.

I am opening to using existing somewhere if it exists but I was unable to find one that meets my needs. I was looking at using this package for converting an image to ANSI - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-art

Once it was converted I was planning to replace all the characters one by one with my sequence.

Then finally was going to use this to convert the ANSI back into an image - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-to-svg

Comment: do you have an example? what is ansi art?

Comment: @NinaScholz The first link answers your question.